# fixed record size file in perl when record consists of utf-8 and ascii

Tags: perl

I want to create a file having fixed records using perl where each record may consists of ASCII or Unicode characters so that I can assess that file as random access file.

In record I have three strings str1,str2 and str3 with the maximum number of characters say 100,60,40 respectively and any sting may contain ASCII or UTF-8 characters.

I am using perl pack/unpack function like below but couldn't get expected result.

```
open (FILE,">>:utf8",filename) or die "can't open\n";
$record=pack("U100 U60 U40",$str1,$str2,$str3);
print FILE $record;
```

to read this

```
open (FILE,"<:utf8",filename) or die "can't open\n";
seek(FILE,$buffer,200);
@data=unpack("U100 U60 U40",$buffer);
print @data;
```

Please help me how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean "fixed" for bytes or characters?

Comment: I mean bytes.My main concern is to create an random access file which can contain utf characters.

Comment: What do you want to do if a character cannot fit in the fixed length record?

Comment: @choroba- i m already putting constraint that three strings can have maximum 50,30,20 characters.Hence I can take maximum size to fit them in fixed length records.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so "ASCII or UTF-8" is the same as just "UTF-8".

Secondly, a "character" is an element of a string. They're not a storage format, and they don't have a specific size, so field lengths can't be measured in characters. The fields can be measured in *bytes*, in *Unicode code points*, or in a number of other units, but not in *characters*.

If the field length are measured in bytes, the amount of padding required varies based on the size of the encoded text, so you need to encode before you pack.

```
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );

open(my $fh, '>>:raw',  $filename)
   or die("Can't open $filename: $!\n");

my $record = pack 'a100 a60 a40', map encode_utf8($_), $str1, $str2, $str3;
print $fh $record;
```

If the far less likely scenario that the field length are measured in Unicode code points, you need to encode after you pack.

```
open(my $fh, '>>:utf8',  $filename)
   or die("Can't open $filename: $!\n");

my $record = pack 'a100 a60 a40', $str1, $str2, $str3;
print $fh $record;
```

(In both cases, use `a` to pack with NULs, and `A` to pack with spaces.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Parse::FixedLength](http://metacpan.org/pod/Parse%3a%3aFixedLength)

Module is great for this, something like this should help explain:

```
use Parse::FixedLength;
my $parser = Parse::FixedLength->new([
    str1    =>  100,
    str2    =>  60,
    str3    =>  40,
]);  
open (FILE,"<:utf8",filename) or die "can't open\n";
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
  my %vals = ('str1' => $str1,
              'str2' => $str2,
              'str3' => $str3,
             );
  print = $parser->pack(\%vals);
}
close FILE;
```

Comment: Hi Analog,

I am not looking for ASCII character packing. I want to pack unicode strings into fixed record size; to write into a file so that I could make random access file and could able to search into that file like  "record_number X record_size".

Please check the CPAN link you provided where module description clearly tell that Parse::FixedLength is for ASCII. Perl default pack/unpack is enough to do this in one line.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: dont use barewords as filehandle name

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of pack templates is not precise. You need the `a` template for byte strings. You have to encode the strings also to get the bytes out of them.

The following script creates two records and reads back the second one.  The strings are truncated at the given size, i.e. possibly in the middle of a multibyte character.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use Encode;

my $filename = 'utf.txt';
my @sizes    = (8, 4, 2);
my $mask     = join ' ', map "a$_", @sizes;
my $sum      = 0;
$sum        += $_ for @sizes;


sub record {
    return map shift(@_) x ($_ + 10), @sizes;
}


sub output {
    open my $FILE, '>>', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    my $record = pack $mask, map { Encode::encode('utf8', $_) } record(@_);
    print $FILE $record;
    close $FILE;
}


sub input {
    my $n = shift;
    open my $FILE, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!\n";
    warn  $sum * ($n - 1);
    seek $FILE, $sum * ($n - 1), 0;
    read $FILE, my ($buffer), $sum;
    my @items = unpack $mask, $buffer;
    say for @items;
}


use utf8;
output(qw/ø ¶ đ/);
output(qw/Č á ∀/);
input(2);
```

Comment: `use bytes;` is deprecated since using it is just plain wrong. Does it even do anything in your code?

Comment: @ikegami: I had the impression it did, but now I see it does not. Thanks.

Comment: Hi choroba-- below is a rough structure of the programme for ASCII. You can change the length of the string as your choice.I am using 300 and 200 ;you may use (30,20) or whatever be. The output will remain same.

#!/usr/bin/perl
my $str1='abcd';
my $str2='defjklm';
my $record=pack("A300 A200",$str1,$str2);
unlink "myfile.txt";
open (FILE,"+>>myfile.txt") or die "not able to open file";
print FILE $record;
($str1,$str2)=('nfg','A');
my $record=pack("A300 A200",$str1,$str2);
print FILE $record;
seek(FILE,500,0);
read(FILE,$buffer,500);
my @data=unpack("A300 A200",$buffer);
print "@data";